# How to interact directly with Safe smart contracts WITHOUT using safe SDK (raw interaction using ethersjs or web3)? Can you provide an example?

Tags: gnosis-safe

i would like to know how to interact with a Safe smart contract and execute the 'execTransaction' providing raw data to all the required fields. The main issue here is how to calculate the signature and execute the tx for a multiSend transaction. You have examples of how you can do it with 1 transaction and using the safeSdk and safe APIs but there isn't any complete example (createTransaction, addData, sign transaction and execute) of how can be done using only etherjs or web3 libraries. Lets assume that you need only 1 signature for the execution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Could you add some context why you want to avoid the use of the Safe{Core} SDK, as it is a tool that facilitates all the interaction with Safe contracts, speeding the development and offering a better user experience when working on tasks like yours.
The SDK uses ethers.js and web3.js internally, so you can just extract the code from it and copy-paste it in your code base.